# Angular material progress linear bar not updating with firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-material, firebase-storage

I'm using firebase to upload images and angular material to style my app but I'm having issues updating the value attribute on the `<md-progress-linear>` directive.

The variable does update every time the `next` function runs, which is every few seconds until the upload finishes. This can be proven by logging `vm.imgProgress` to the console (which I'm doing in the `next` function). However the value on the directive doesn't update unless I focus on a form field.

Here's some of my code, I hope it's useful.

HTML

```
<md-progress-linear md-mode="determinate" value="{{vm.imgProgress}}"></md-progress-linear>
```

JS

```
angular
.module('app.posts')
.controller('PostsController', PostsController);

PostsController.$inject = ['$firebaseArray', '$window'];

function PostsController($firebaseArray, $window) {
  var vm = this;

  vm.imgProgress = 0;

  function uploadImage() {
    var file = document.getElementById('file-input').files[0];
    var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/' + file.name).put(file);

function next(snapshot) {
  // Get task progress, including the number of bytes uploaded and the total number of bytes to be uploaded
  vm.imgProgress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
  console.log('Upload is ' + vm.imgProgress + '% done');
  switch (snapshot.state) {
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
      console.log('Upload is paused');
    break;
    case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
      console.log('Upload is running');
    break;
  }
}

function complete() {
  vm.newPost.imgURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
}

uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED, next, error, complete);

  }

}
```

Comment: Try injecting `$scope` and `$timeout` then wrap the assignment to **vm.imgProgress** in **next()** with `$timeout`: `$timeout(function () ...{});

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution base on @camden_kid answer

HTML:

```
<md-progress-circular md-mode="determinate" value="{{percent}}"></md-progress-circular>
```

JS:

```
        $scope.uploadfile = function (ev) {

            var file = $scope.mp3;

            var metadata = { contentType: 'audio/mpeg', };
            var uploadTask = storage.ref().child('songs/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);

            uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
                    function (snapshot) {

                        $timeout(function () {
                            $scope.percent = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                        });
                        console.log('Upload is ' + $scope.percent + '% done');
                        switch (snapshot.state) {
                            case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED:
                                //console.log('Upload is paused');
                                break;
                            case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING:
                                //console.log('Upload is running');
                                break;
                        }
                    });
        };
```